# Background task is starting unreliably

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have an UWP app that is dependant on a background task. This task should thus be running all the time when the user is using the device. I have tried registering it with these triggers:

```
ApplicationTrigger _AppTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
builderInApp.SetTrigger(_AppTrigger);
builderSession.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.SessionConnected, false));
builderPower.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.PowerStateChange, false));
```

But it seems like sometimes the task does not start. It starts 90% of the time after a restart or shutdown, continues 100% of the time after energy-saving mode, works 100% of the time if the system is just idle, about 50% after a Hybernation and only rarely if I do Energy Saver and then hybernate without unlocking.

Is there something I can do to make this more reliable? I have already added `<rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>` and enabled user management by User instead of windows.

Should I add some more triggers? Which ones? Is there another way to get better reliability? I don't mind using a .Net component if that would help, but my background task does have to be UWP.

Other question I have about this:

If I have triggered the background with trigger a, and trigger a fires again, does the process launch a second time, get cancelled and relaunched, or nothing happens?

Same question if I have triggered the background with trigger a, and trigger b fires, does the process launch a second time, get cancelled and relaunched, or nothing happens?

Edit: I have tried using `StartupTask`, but cannot get it to trigger after hybernation.

Comment: To make it work while in battery saver mode, you have to request accesskind "alwaysAllowed": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundexecutionmanager.requestaccesskindasync

Comment: Regarding the 90% success rate after restart: have you looked if there are any crashes or logs being reported? Wondering whether it get triggered, but then failed for some reason.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Set it. And yes, thank you. The task at startup was sometimes crashing. I added a timer, so it now waits some time before trying to do anything and now it works.

Comment: Is everything working now for you, or some things are still open? Might want to update the question, or ask separate questions for this different topics, otherwise it's hard for us to articulate a straight answer.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I am still testing! Thanks for asking. It seems like there were multiple issues (crashing if it started too soon and it being launched multiple times because of different triggers). For now it seems to be running all the time, I will update incase it does not work out. Would you want to write a summary as an answer, so I can accept it?